# Square of perimeter $[-2, 2] \times [-2, 2]$: What Does This Notation Mean?

Tags: geometry, notation

What does the notation $[-2, 2] \times [-2, 2]$ mean? My problem specifically says a square of perimeter $[-2, 2] \times [-2, 2]$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I think so; in the $xy$ Cartesian plane is the square with vertex $(-2,-2), (-2,2), (2,2), (2,-2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, then their Cartesian product is
$$A\times B=\{(a,b)\ |\ a\in A,\ b\in B\}.$$

So your example is 
$$[-2,2]\times [-2,2]=\{(x,y)\ |\ x\in[-2,2],\ y\in[-2,2]\}$$

So $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$ is the set of all points in the square with vertices $(\pm2,\pm2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$ denotes a square (inclusive interior) with the corners

$$(-2,-2),\quad(-2,2),\quad(2,2),\quad(2,-2).$$

---

**Some explanation**

$[a,b]$ is a *closed interval* and means all numbers between (and inclusive) $a$ and $b$. In your case, the closed inteval $[-2,2]$ means all numbers $x$ with $-2\le x\le 2$.

When you have two sets of numbers $A$ and $B$, and you write $A\times B$, then this denotes all *pairs of numbers* $(a,b)$ with $a$ is a number from $A$, and $b$ is a number from $B$. So again, in your case of $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$, this is a set which contains e.g. the pair $(0, 0.5)$ because $0$ is between $-2$ and $2$ in the first interval, and $0.5$ is between $-2$ and $2$ in the second interval.